# Limit on memory registrations and Open MPI

Tags: performance, memory, hpc, openmpi

When I run my program I get this warning from Open MPI:

```
libibverbs: Warning: RLIMIT_MEMLOCK is 32768 bytes.
    This will severely limit memory registrations.
```

I checked the Open MPI FAQ, and they explain how to solve it. My question is: The program is working until the end, is this warning going to affect the efficiency or the results? If Open MPI doesn't have enough locked memory, how is it going to deal with it?

---

Edit:

They told me that this is a warning printed by the OpenFabrics' InfiniBand software. However, I am not using the software which is printing this error because I am running the code on a single node not connected to an InfiniBand fabric (I didn't understand this from reading the Open MPI FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using OpenFabrics-based networks, you can ignore this warning.

Or, you can disable OpenFabrics services on your machine(s), and then (IIRC) you might not get this warning at all.  I don't remember offhand, to be honest.  :-)

Comment: InfiniBand is one OpenFabrics-based network, yes.  iWARP and RoCE are two others.

Answer (score 1):

One can completely disable the OpenIB BTL module in Open MPI using the following MCA parameter:

```
mpirun --mca btl ^openib ...
```

This will prevent Open MPI from trying to initialise and use the InfiniBand HCA and the warning will be gone.